# Does screen resolution break selenium tests?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've coded my scripts using a screen resolution of 1920x1080(16:9) and now I'm running on a jenkins slave which I noticed has 1024x768(4:3) and tests just fail. Is this because the screen resolution is breaking the DOM? I'm thinking that this is because failures are caused by elements not being found (not quite sure if the right word) but I would think that even if layout is not responsive elements should be found? Anyone know if this is the cause and how to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

I did come across the same issue and I resolved it by setting the dimensions to the resolution I wanted:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

It worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

Screen resolution can't affect DOM. However, it is well known issue with Selenium tests and running tests in different resolutions - element may need to be scrolled into view before it can be interacted with. Depending on particular driver you use (e.g. chromedriver), you need to ensure element is visible before you interact with it.

If you need more detailed help, screenshot, browser name, your code and stack trace can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

run >> services.msc >> stop the system service which you want to change resolution (Jenkins.exe) >> right click >> Properties >> Log On TAB >> Local System Account >> Check Allow service to interact with Desktop >> then it will take the resolution of the monitor you currently use.

Make sure you put browser.driver.manage().window().maximize(); on the your onPrepare: metod of protractor.conf.js

Comment: Do you know what to do if you are running Jenkins as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Typically protractor scrolls to click a button if it finds it with a locator in the DOM.
 There are some edge cases where it cant but if your page can compress it self quite a bit, you shouldn't have problems. You can set the resolution for the protractor to set a window size before a test as found in [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/872).

Comment: why do you assume this is protractor?

Comment: Hah I actually did that? Funny. Anyway. Whatever framework you are using, these commands are the way to go on your remote server, and the cause is probably the same too.